# Ruby on Rails can't convert String into Integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, hash

I am sending JSON data to a controller which parses it.

**ROR Code**

```
Class.where(challenge_id:challenge.id,song_id:song_hash['song_id']).first
```

The **error** is

```
can't convert String into Integer
```

I even change the `song_id:song_hash['song_id']` to `song_id:song_hash['song_id'].to_i` but it didn't work

The **Hash DATA** is

```
{"session_token"=>"Xt9toEzHI3bYXeJNkenyqg", "challenge"=>{"challenge_id"=>"15", "player_name"=>"usman", "guessed_songs"=>{"0"=>{"song_id"=>"10", "guessed"=>"YES"}, "1"=>{"song_id"=>"11", "guessed"=>"YES"}, "2"=>{"song_id"=>"12", "guessed"=>"YES"}, "3"=>{"song_id"=>"13", "guessed"=>"YES"}, "4"=>{"song_id"=>"15", "guessed"=>"YES"}}, "player_status"=>{"0"=>{"coins"=>"20", "points"=>"0", "player_name"=>"usman"}, "1"=>{"coins"=>"20", "points"=>"0", "player_name"=>"Usman"}}}}
```

Couldn't find what is not converting into integer

Comment: The JSON DATA that you provided is not `json` at all. `{"song_id":q1,"guessed":"YES"}` is not `json`. {"song_id":"q1","guessed":"YES"} is `json`. Notice the double quotes

Comment: Apart from that, the clue is "song_id" : q1. q1 is NOTHING. Not a string, nor an integer. But rails is expecting song_id to be an integer, but its helpless

Comment: @Vineeth actually Q1, Q2 are the variables. the data is in integer suppose 1,2,3,4,5.. I've edited the Q

Comment: what is this `challenge.id`  ? is it getting integer

Comment: Can you inspect with pry or debugger just in the line before and post the values of challenge.id and song_hash['song_id']?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd guess that your `song_hash` isn't really a Hash at all, it is an Array. Probably this array from the incoming data:

```
"guessed_songs":[{"song_id":1,"guessed":"YES"},{"song_id":2,"guessed":"YES"},{"song_id":3,"guessed":"YES"},{"song_id":4,"guessed":"YES"},{"song_id":5,"guessed":"YES"}],
```

The error you're seeing is almost always a result of trying to index an Array as though it was a Hash. For example:

```
>> song_hash = [ ]
>> song_hash['song_id']
TypeError: can't convert String into Integer
```

The only indexing in your code is:

```
song_hash['song_id']
```

and that is certainly something being indexed with a string so it matches the TypeError you're seeing. Changing that to:

```
song_hash['song_id'].to_i
```

won't help because the offending `[]` method will be called before `to_i` gets a chance to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Probably any of your fields(`challenge_id`, `song_id`) is integer but you insert it a string 
also in you json there is a lot of ambigous thing can not understand `challenge_id":cId` is it a integer

As per your

for all song id

```
      irb(main):016:0* song_hash = {"guessed_songs"=>{"0"=>{"song_id"=>"10", "guessed"=>"YES"}, "1"=>{"song_id"=>"11", "guessed"=>"YES"}, "2"=>{"song_id"=>"12", "guessed"=>"YES"}, "3"=>{"song_id"=>"13", "guessed"=>"YES"}, "4"=>{"song_id"=>"15", "guessed"=>"YES"}}}

      => {"guessed_songs"=>{"0"=>{"song_id"=>"10", "guessed"=>"YES"}, "1"=>{"song_id"=>"11", "guessed"=>"YES"}, "2"=>{"song_id"=>"12", "guessed"=>"YES"}, "3"=>{"song_id"=>"13", "guessed"=>"YES"}, "4"=>{"song_id"=>"15", "guessed"=>"YES"}}}


      irb(main):018:0> song_hash["guessed_songs"].each do |key,song|
      irb(main):019:1* puts song["song_id"].to_i
      irb(main):020:1> end
      =>10
      =>11
      =>12
      =>13
      =>15
      => {"0"=>{"song_id"=>"10", "guessed"=>"YES"}, "1"=>{"song_id"=>"11", "guessed"=>"YES"}, "2"=>{"song_id"=>"12", "guessed"=>"YES"}, "3"=>{"song_id"=>"13", "guessed"=>"YES"}, "4"=>{"song_id"=>"15", "guessed"=>"YES"}}
```

so in loop you can try this

```
           pm=PlaylistMembership.where(challenge_id:challenge.id,song_id:song["song_id"].to_i).first
```

Comment: tried it, not working...

Comment: what is `challenge` ? you did `challenge.id`

Comment: please put your `song_hash`

Comment: undefined local variable or method `song' for #<ChallengesController:0x15cb784f>

Comment: Edit the Question for Hash

Comment: look into edited edited post

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`song_id:song_hash[:song_id]`